# call method by two hour time interval. Even when app is closed or in background

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, nstimeinterval

i want to create an app. which call method by two hour time interval. (like i want to fetch RSS feed after every two hour) so how can i do this?? i know by using timer i can check time but where should i write code of fetching data so its called automatically wheather app in background or app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the UIBackgroundModes, certainly "Newsstand downloads":

The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.

Also you can visit [Raywenderlich guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial)